# Using Facebook for iOS SDK 3.1 how to post to friend's timeline avoiding deprecated headers

Tags: ios, facebook, publish, friend, facebook-timeline

Given that Facebook has just completed "Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API" posted at their roadmap completed changes page.

evidently due to some abuses

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

The recommended approach in the tutorial "Publish to Feed" posted at their developer site
now restricts to posting to your own timeline with graphPath "me/feed".

This development obviates good approaches suggested by other stack overflow contributor's.

So that leaves Henry Zhang and others recommending the Feed Dialog with it's deprecated headers posted at

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/

so Facebook tells you in "Step 2: Add the Backward Compatibility Headers"

Even their posted tutorial for Games uses the deprecated headers. However, the deprecated headers cannot be used in conjunction with new FacebookSDK.

Perhaps I am being stubborn to want to stick with the current SDK release, but has anyone succeeded posting to a friend's timeline from iOS importing only the FacebookSDK 3.1. I am really quite surprised that Facebook is recommending building apps with deprecated code, but I can't seem to find any other way to do this. The other parts of the 3.1 SDK work well and I don't want to toss the baby out with the water.

Comment: Been there, had the exact same thoughts. Eventually I used the deprecated headers. Very reluctant to do so but found no other way as of now.

Comment: @Stavash Thanks for the candor. I have authentication via session state changes, friend picker and profile picture all working in SDK 3.1. Are there good active links to implement this capability in the older SDK? I had tried isolating the feed dialog code into a separate object hoping to isolate the older SDK but of course even that introduces the duplicate protocol definitions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On reading the summary information in the Facebook.h file, I have come to realize that it imports FacebookSDK.h which picks up the 3.1 SDK interfaces I had implemented. With that knowledge and some careful editing from the feed dialog example I now can send a message to a friend's timeline alongside the 3.1 elements. I still look forward to the next release and getting everything in one SDK. Thanks.